How to format printing an array in Python
I have an array of 10 elements and I can each of the elements print on a new line formatted 6.2f with
print(f'{myArray:6.2f}', sep="\n")
But I would like to create string containing what needs to be printed, add a few things and print that string, like:
 text = 'something ' + f'{myArray:6.2f}' + ' rest'
 print (text)

How can I make that each element of myArray will be on a new line and formatted in text?

There has to be an existing Q&A showing how to combine format + generator expression + str.join

Yes, I know that there 'has to be' an existing Q&A but I didn't find it and unfortumally you didn't show me. I don/t aks here because I'm too lazy to search myself.

Can you show what exactly your input and expected output is? In some comments you mentioned nested lists but the question doesn't say that.

Thanks for reply,  Expected outcome: "results are:\n    1.23     -2.34     12.87 \n    -3.45     8.98     14.38 \n  2.97   1.23  75.32\n enter new data"
Input (after reading an answer): text = ''.join([f'\n{item}' for item in myArray])      text = "results are:" + text + "\nenter new data")
Indeed I have a nested list but didn't mention it as I thought/hoped I could figure out myself handling the nested list once I knew the first step

Thanks for ALL the replies, they all helped me towards the solution including expansion of the list requiering different formats to use.
text = "results:\n" + '\n'.join(''.join(f"{x[0]:6.2f}  {x[1]:6.2f}  {x[2]:6.4f}  {x[3]:3.1f}".format(*x)) for x in myArray) + "\n Enter new data"
Only thing left is that I would like to put the different formats into a list and use that for each nested list of myArray.

You can try this:
for item in myArray:
        print (f'something {item:6.2f} rest', sep="\n"))


Try:
arr=map(float, range(1,11))
print('\n'.join([f'something {item:6.2f} rest' for item in arr]))

Prints:
something   1.00 rest
something   2.00 rest
something   3.00 rest
something   4.00 rest
something   5.00 rest
something   6.00 rest
something   7.00 rest
something   8.00 rest
something   9.00 rest
something  10.00 rest


Thank you. but what if myArray consists of a list of floats like myArray[0] = [1.23456, 2.4680, 13.579] etc instead of single float? How can I print the contents of myArray[0] using 6.2f ?

So your array is nested? Something like [[1.23,3.45,6.78],[9.10,10.23,11.22],...]?

Indeed, currently the nested lists all contain 3 floats, but it might be I will add some ints and/or texts to each of the nested lists. (All nested lists will have the same layout)

Make a template and apply it elementwise. Format & f-string notation do not require an explicit cast to string which make them preferable wrt an explicit string join, str.join.
Notice that for the f-string notation {} are escaped by nesting them {{}}. Then, to use format, you need a further nested pair.
You can pass your own element separator to the print to customize, with no extra manipulation, the final output.
myArray = [[1.23456, 2.4680, 13.579], [1, 2, 3]]

sf = 6  # significant figures
dp = 2  # decimal places

apply_float_pattern = f"{{:{sf}.{dp}f}}".format
el_SEP = ', '
line_SEP = '\n'

# method 1
for a in myArray:
    print(*map(apply_float_pattern, a), sep=el_SEP)

Ouptut
  1.23,   2.47,  13.58
  1.00,   2.00,   3.00

or by constructing a single string representing the whole output
# method 2
output = line_SEP.join(el_SEP.join(map(apply_float_pattern, a)) for a in myArray)
print(output)

